# How to send/receive messages from every client with RabbitMQ Java

Tags: java, rabbitmq, broadcast

How to implement the following situation on Java with RabbitMQ:

[image: sharing messagges every node]

where every node, send messages to all other nodes and every node receive messages from all other nodes ?

**UPDATE 1:**
I tried to create the above situation with the following code:

**ReceiveLogs.java**

```
public class ReciveLogs {

...

    public void start() throws IOException, TimeoutException, InterruptedException {

        connection = factory.newConnection();

        channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(coda, false, false, false, null);
        channel.exchangeDeclare(exName, BuiltinExchangeType.FANOUT);
        channel.queueBind(coda, exName, "");
        channel.basicPublish(exName, codaX, null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        System.out.println(" ReceiveLogs Sent: " + message);

        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                    byte[] body) throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(" ReceiveLogs RECEIVED:" + message);
            }
        };
        channel.basicConsume(codaX, true, consumer);
    }

}
```

**EmitLog.java**

```
public class EmitLog {

...

    public void start() throws IOException, TimeoutException {

        connection = factory.newConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.exchangeDeclare(exName, BuiltinExchangeType.FANOUT);
        channel.queueDeclare(codaX, false, false, false, null);
        channel.queueBind(codaX, exName, "");

        Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
            @Override
            public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                    byte[] body) throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println(" ROUTER Received: '" + message);
            }
        };
        String message = channel.basicConsume(codaX, true, consumer);

        channel.basicPublish(exName, "", null, message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("ROUTER Sent: " + message);

        channel.close();
        connection.close();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a "fanout" exchange.

This is the setup you need to do:

1. Create a fanount exchange
2. Create 3 queues, one for each node. Say Q1, Q2 and Q3 corresponding to C1, C2 and C3.
3. Bind all queues (Q1, Q2 and Q3) to the fanount exchange created in step 1

Listening Code:

1. Create a listener for each of the nodes. For example, C1 node listens for messages on Queue "Q1", C2 for "Q2" and so on.

Publishing:
- Whenever you want to send a message, publish the message on broadcast exchange you created.

There is small caveat here: If C1 publishes the message, then C1 receives the same message as well. So, if you don't any node to process the same message it published, then you can use one of the attributes in the message to filter it out.

Further documentation:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-fanout

Comment: your idea is most interesting! But I have another doubt. C1, C2, C3 must be both Consumer and Publisher at the same time. is it possible?

Comment: They can be both producer and consumer. No problems with it at all. RabbitMQ identifies a connection (either producer or consumer) via a tcp connection. These tcp connections can come from multiple threads in the same process or different processes. It doesn't matter.

Comment: I update the above question with more details, I tried to implement what you said, but I believe it doesn't work.

Comment: I would be helpful if you can provide more details regarding what you tried and what didn't work. Are you having problems connecting to rabbitmq from 2 different threads in a process? Is the publishing working properly? Is the listening working properly?

Comment: @apatniv, have you found a resolution for this question?. I am having a similar challenge. I have an App A (message sender), App B Part 1 (Startup function - message consumer), App B Part 2 (Automation framework). The message send and receive concept works for me, but making the receiver part of my automation framework poses some challenges, I am not sure how to take the messages off from the queue, essentially the incoming message should now trigger my framework to do something with the incoming parameters. please help.